# Print library value from function on display

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm trying to print the return value(WiFi.localIP) on my display from the library [ESP8266WiFi](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html). But I'm getting an error. For the display I'm using the [SSD1306](https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306) library.

The purpose of this is to print the IP adress of the ESP8266 on the display.

ERROR:

```
Arduino: 1.8.16 (Windows 10), Board: "LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini, 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"


C:\Users\lauwy\Documents\Arduino\Testsketch\Project\Code\WEB\V4.2\V4.2.ino: In function 'void connectToWifi()':

V4.2:38:32: error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]

   38 |   String ipstat = &WiFi.localIP();

      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

V4.2:38:19: error: conversion from 'IPAddress*' to non-scalar type 'String' requested

   38 |   String ipstat = &WiFi.localIP();

      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

exit status 1

taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]
```

CODE:

```
#include <Wire.h>  
#include "SSD1306.h"
SSD1306  display(0x3C, D2, D5);

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid     = "*****************"; //Enter network SSID 
const char* password = "*****************"; //Enter network PASSWORD 

WiFiServer server(80);

void connectToWifi(){
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.begin();

  String ipstat = &WiFi.localIP();
 
  display.init();
  display.flipScreenVertically();
  display.drawString(0, 0, ipstat);
  display.display();
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `toString()` method from the [ESP8266WiFi library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/da6ec83b5fdbd5b02f04cf143dcf8e158a8cfd36/cores/esp8266/IPAddress.cpp#L162) (line 162-173).

```
String ipstat = WiFi.localIP().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- You are affecting a pointer to initialize a no-pointer variable (with the '&')
- The compiler does not manage to cast an object IPAddress in String.

The use of a function "to_string" would be better.

```
String ipstat = to_string(WiFi.localIP());
```

Of course you have to code this function if it does not exist ;)

Comment: it doesn't exist